# Using GeofencingApi and .setResultCallback() in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, location, android-geofence, location-services

Let's say I have a BroadcastReceiver in my Main Activity, which implements `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,ResultCallback<Status>`.

Now, I want to add my geofences via:

```
LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(mGoogleApiClient, getGeofencingRequest(),getGeofencePendingIntent()).setResultCallback(this);
```

However, I get an error that I can't use `this` in .`setResultCallback`, which probably has something to do with it being called in the Broadcastreceiver.
Since the Result is being processed in `onResult()`, how do I get `onResult()` in .`setResultCallback`?

My broadcastreceiver:

```
WakefulBroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new WakefulBroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            SharedPreferences mahprefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplication());
            Integer radius = mahprefs.getInt("radiusnumber",500);
            String lat = (String) intent.getExtras().get("Latitude");
            String longi = (String) intent.getExtras().get("Longitude");
            Double alt = intent.getDoubleExtra("Altitude", 0);
            Boolean geofenceexists = mahprefs.getBoolean("geofenceexists",false);
            Boolean scharf = mahprefs.getBoolean("scharf",false);
            Float accuracys = intent.getFloatExtra("Accuracy", 0);
            String providertype = intent.getStringExtra("Provider");
            Number speed = intent.getFloatExtra("Speed", 0);
            latText.setText(lat);
            longText.setText(longi);
            altitude.setText(String.valueOf(alt)+getString(R.string.meter));
            accuracy.setText(String.valueOf(accuracys)+getString(R.string.meter));
            lcprovidertype.setText(String.valueOf(providertype));
            Float bearing = intent.getFloatExtra("Bearing", 0);
            Log.v("INTENTgetextra", lat);
            Log.v("INTENTgetextra", longi);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mahprefs.edit();
            editor.putString("latitude", lat);
            editor.putString("longitude", longi);
            editor.putString("altitude", String.valueOf(alt));
            editor.putString("speed", String.valueOf(speed));
            editor.putString("bearing", String.valueOf(bearing));
            editor.apply();

            //Geofence Managment
            if(scharf){
                if(!geofenceexists){
                    mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder().setRequestId("alarmgeofence").setCircularRegion(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(longi), radius)
                            .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                            .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                            .build());
                    LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(mGoogleApiClient, getGeofencingRequest(),getGeofencePendingIntent()).setResultCallback(this);
                    Log.v("GEOFENCES",mGeofenceList.toString());
                    editor.putBoolean("geofenceexists",true);
                    editor.apply();
                }
            } else{
                try {
                    mGeofenceList.removeAll(mGeofenceList);
                    LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(mGoogleApiClient, getGeofencePendingIntent()).setResultCallback(onResult(Status null); // Result processed in onResult().
                    editor.putBoolean("geofenceexists",false);
                    editor.apply();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }




        }
    };
```

In activity onCreate:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
```

My Activity: `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,ResultCallback<Status>` (And yes all the necessary methods are imported)

And my imports:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
```

Comment: Could you share your imports and the function that contains the call to `.setResultCallback(this);`?

Comment: @antonio sure, look at my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that your `MainActivity` implements `ResultCallback`, so your code should look like this:

```
LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(mGoogleApiClient, getGeofencingRequest(),getGeofencePendingIntent()).setResultCallback(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: Yep, that seems to be it. Thanks! I'll accept your answer as soon as i can.